# What options are there for Free for commercial use NoSql Datastores for the .NET world?

Tags: nosql

I've been looking around....

- MongoDB seems to require a commercial license. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Licensing
- RavenDB has quite a costly scheme.  http://ravendb.net/licensing

CouchDB, seems to be free for commercial use? But requires Apache, which is a bit of a pain.

Are there any other good options for .NET?

Comment: I don't think that MongoDb requires a commercial license.

Comment: Ans why does CouchDB require "Apache"? What do you mean whith "Apache"? The Apache web server?

Comment: Theo, according to the Mongo link I posted above, I think it does, unless I misunderstood it

CouchDB seems to be hosted with an Apache webserver?  again might be wrong, happy to be corrected!

Comment: CouchDB doesn't need the apache webserver.

Comment: Here http://blog.mongodb.org/post/103832439/the-agpl#disqus_thread it is stated "Note however that it is NOT required that applications using mongo be published."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding, MongoDB is open source and free to use. There are two license types: AGPL v3.0 and a commercial license. There are a few minor restrictions with the AGPL 3.0, so some may need to remove these restrictions with a commercial license, but most probably won't.

So in short, I believe it is free and can most likely suit your needs.

Comment: You can use it just as a back-end (for free) but if it is part of your product, you have to buy a commercial license. So it's useless for anything other than a website.

Answer (score 2):

It may or may not apply to you: if you're going to use RavenDB for a startup company, you may request a free license.

Comment: sure,  but thats more a commercial strategy/bet to get to get conversions to paying customers.

Comment: Perhaps it is. Still I think it's decent of Ayende to offer this.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there's nothing preventing you from using a table in an ordinary SQL database as a simple repository for key-value pairs, which is essentially what a NoSQL database is.

This has the added benefit of still allowing you to use SQL where it is appropriate.

Comment: yes, that provides simple key value, but most of the NoSql type stores provide a bunch of other features as well, replication, sharding, querying, etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra uses Facebook's "thrift" (now Apache Thrift) RPC mechanism for its client layer. This is capable of generating C# output, which you can compile into a .NET assembly and call from a MS CLR application.

Whether Cassandra itself does what you want, is very much dependent upon what you want *is*.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mcintyre321/PieDb is a very basic MIT-licenced embedded document db wot I wrote

It

- writes objects to app_data using json.net serialized documents
- uses Lucene.Net.Linq to provide basic IQueryable support
- optimistic concurrency
- requires no configuration

It would be nice to get some other developers behind it, as it's only had about a weekend of work on it, but it works for simple cases as a RavenDb replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Google has released a beta preview of their [Cloud Datastore](https://developers.google.com/datastore/) (previously only available for App Engine apps), but now can be used via their [JSON API](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta1/).  It is free up to 1GB with 50K calls per day and there is a paid option after that.

GCD is rather low level, but I wrote a .NET ORM for it called Pogo that supports LINQ.  The API is inspired by the RavenDB client API.

The source code and documentation for Pogo is available here - http://code.thecodeprose.com/pogo, and it is also available on [Nuget](https://nuget.org/packages/pogo/).

Answer (score 0):

For .Net there is also FatDB, which we used for a smaller project. They have a one year demo version : http://fatcloud.com/

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on some of thee feature offered by fatcloud?

Comment: on top of the NoSQL database they offer a work queue and a file management system. You can just create and deploy your app on their platform and all the back-end wiring and rebalancing is done for you.